# Sprite kit physics box with curved path incorrect

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

Im trying to make a round arc shaped object that if a line is drawn through the shape the line the collision is detected and removed. I created a node with the following code

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(-100, 0)];
[path addArcWithCenter:CGPointZero radius:100 startAngle:M_PI endAngle:0 clockwise:NO];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(85, 0)];
[path addArcWithCenter:CGPointZero radius:85 startAngle:0 endAngle:M_PI clockwise:YES];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(-100, 0)];
[path closePath];

SKShapeNode *shapeNode = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithPath:path.CGPath centered:YES];
shapeNode.fillColor = [SKColor whiteColor];
shapeNode.strokeColor = [SKColor whiteColor];
SKTexture *texture = [self.view textureFromNode:shapeNode];
sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:texture];
sprite.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithPolygonFromPath:shapeNode.path];
sprite.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = 0x1 << 0;
sprite.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = 0x1 << 1;
sprite.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
sprite.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0x0;
sprite.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
[self addChild: sprite];
```

In my test code I implemented that if you drag and drop from one position to another a node with a physics body using: `[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeFromPoint: toPoint:]` it seems to call didBeginContact if the line is in the middle of the arc as if the physics body resembles a semi circle.

[image: Screen shot]

The detection on the other side of the arc works fine. The lines of view.showsPhysics  seem to be correct and I've also tested this with objects falling on the arc. Im not sure if this is a glitch with sprite kit or a mistake I'm making.

The game I'm making needs this functionality to have arcs as obstacles as well as line and obstacle intersection detection.

Comment: By using [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromPath:] instead of [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithPolygonFromPath:] it seemed to correct objects colliding with it but the line physics body is not calling didBeginContact

Comment: Does your line have an edge loop, or is it a polygon?  Edge loops will not collide with each other.  Polygons and edge loops will.

Comment: When it has an edge loop the collisions work with moving objects but when creating a physics body on top of it that intersects the physics body it doesnt seem to register the collision. When its a polygon it has this weird behaviour of treating the physics body like a semi cricle with all collisions